# I always get missing $ when using \begin{equation}

Tags: errors, equations

I am currently writing my master's thesis on LaTeX, and I keep getting problems each time I use the `\begin{equation}` syntax, this is what I'm using

```
 \begin{equation}

 DTW(X,Y)= \underset{w_x,w_y}{\text{min}}\sum_{k=1}^{K}d(x_{w_x}(k),y_{w_y}(k))

  \end{equation}
```

and this is what I get

```
! Missing $ inserted
```

so far I have read that `\begin{equation}` already opens a math environment
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: remove the blank lines.